# Get the publishing date of a web page

Tags: java

Hi, in Google when I search, I can see the publishing date of any URL.

Can I do something in Android , I have list of urls, I want to get the publishing date of those URL.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it is to send `HEAD` request to the URL and then look at the `Last-Modified` header of the response.  Note though that some web servers may not supply the `LastModified` header, in which case you won't be able to determine this date, however in most cases you should get it.  The code will look something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
String url = "http://example.com/getmethod.aspx?id=111&method=Test";
HttpHead req = new HttpHead(url);
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(req);  
String lastMod = resp.getFirtHeader("Last-Modified")
if(lastMod != null) {
    //parse this string to get a date
    //it will be in this format: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT
}
```

Comment: it always crash in resp.getFirstHeader("Last-Modified") , nullpointerexception, any idea

Comment: @Ali possibly, `client.execute(req)` returns `null`.  You'll need to check what's happening there.  Alternatively, try changing `HttpHead` to `HttpGet` everywhere and see if you get a valid response.

Comment: this line resp.getFirstHeader("Last-Modified").getValue()  get null

Comment: `resp.getFirstHeader` already returns a String.  What is it?  Is it `null`?  If yes, then check all headers.  It's possible that the server didn't return the last-modified date of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Apache HttpComponents. You can find it here: http://hc.apache.org/

EDIT:
You can also use AndroidHttpClient.